# Datatables internationalization (Russian language localization)

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization, internationalization, datatables

Hello all genius users of the stack overflow,
First, i want to say thanks to all of you for all help i have received.

Now here is my question

[image]you can see in the image, that i am using datatables for listing in the admin panel (CMS).

I was able to convert buttons and that search label into russian language.

But apart from that, those "Show  Rows", "show / hide columns", "Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries" and pagination "First Previous Next Last" labels couldn't be translated in russian language as those labels comes from the datatable JS library.

I have already found solution on the datatables site and links are below :

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/

http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Russian#top

https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/

The problem is that, i can not find that how to integrate it in my code.
I searched a lot but couldn't get the instruction to implement it.

```js
function getdatatable(deleteadr, paginate, aoculumn, aoColumnDefs) {

  oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "bs_full",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    sDom: "<'row'<'dataTables_header  clearfix'<'col-md-4'lC><'col-md-8'TRf>r>>t<'row'<'dataTables_footer clearfix'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>> ",
    "bStateSave": true,
    oTableTools: {
      "sRowSelect": "multi",
      "aButtons": [{
          "sExtends": "copy",
          "sButtonText": "copy",
          "mColumns": "visible"
        }, {
          "sExtends": "print",
          "sButtonText": "print",
          "mColumns": "visible"
        }, {
          "sExtends": "csv",
          "sButtonText": "csv",
          "mColumns": "visible"
        }, {
          "sExtends": "xls",
          "sButtonText": "xls",
          "mColumns": "visible"
        }, {
          "sExtends": "pdf",
          "sButtonText": "pdf",
          "mColumns": "visible"
        }, {
          "sExtends": "text",
          "sButtonText": "Delete",
          "fnClick": function(nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
            deleteerows(deleteadr);
          }
        },
        "select_all", "select_none"
      ],

      sSwfPath: BASEURL + "js/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": BASEURL + paginate,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "aoColumns": aoculumn,
    "aoColumnDefs": aoColumnDefs,

    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Search:"
    },
    "bSortCellsTop": true
  });
}
```

```js
 $this - > javascripts = array(
   "modernizrjs" => "js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js",
   "bootstrap" => "js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js",
   "jqueryjs" => "bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "datatable" => "js/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
   "assetsdatatable" => "js/datatables/media/assets/js/datatables.min.js",
   "celsdlreorder" => "js/datatables/extras/ColReorder/media/js/ColReorderwithresize.js",
   "colvis" => "js/datatables/extras/ColVis/media/js/ColVis.js",
   "masdoment" => "js/bootstrap-daterangepicker/moment.min.js",
   "timeag" => "js/timeago/jquery.timeago.min.js",
   // "date"           =>  "js/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js",
   "slimscroll" => "js/jQuery-slimScroll-1.3.0/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
   "slimscrollhorizontal" => "js/jQuery-slimScroll-1.3.0/slimScrollHorizontal.min.js",
   "block" => "js/jQuery-BlockUI/jquery.blockUI.min.js",
   "tabletool" => "js/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.min.js",
   "clipboard" => "js/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js",
   "cellreorder" => "js/datatables/extras/FixedHeader/js/FixedHeader.min.js",
   "cookie" => "js/jQuery-Cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js",
   "griter" => "js/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.min.js",
   "script" => "js/script.js",
   "main" => "js/main.js",
   "isotope" => "js/isotope/jquery.isotope.min.js",
   "imagesloaded" => "js/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.min.js",
   "blockUI" => "js/jQuery-BlockUI/jquery.blockUI.min.js"
 );
```

Please help me out here.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to include language-specific Javascript file right after your library file, in your HTML header.

For this plugin try to change your initialization code:

```
oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
    // insert this section
    "language": {
        "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Russian.json"
    },
    // continue your code
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you include dataTables javascript into HTML?

Comment: Edited the post, try it.

Comment: How can i enable search in Russian language?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ошибка в том что в инициализации таблицы уже был:

(For you error in that in initialising of table already was:)

```
    "oLanguage": {
     "sSearch": "Search:"
    },
```

удали или замени свой `oLanguage` на пример ниже:

(Take away or replace your sSearch example above:)

```
    "oLanguage": {
     "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Russian.json"
    },
```